# Left mouse click stops working in hyper-v after a minute

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, mouse, hyper-v

I'm having a really weird problem with Hyper-V on Windows 8 Pro, and I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Problem:

- I created Win8 vm in Hyper-V and booted it up
- I use vmconnect (right click vm, connect) to connect to the vm
- For the first minute or so, mouse movement/clicking and keyboard all work great
- After about a minute, my left-mouse click stops working.
- Mouse movement, mouse right-click and keyboard all still work great - it's just the left-mouse click that stops working.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 15):

Here's a workaround that appears to resolve the symptom but not the cause.  Be sure that your vmconnect window is not in full screen mode.  You will then see the menu bar at the top. Under the "view" tab, be sure that the "Toolbar" option is checked.  Now you will see a toolbar below the menubar.  Click the pause button and then click the play button on the toolbar.  You should get your left mouse click back and you can go back to full screen mode.  You can repeat this each time you lose the left mouse button.

Comment: rediculous, this is still happening in 2020 with Win10, pause + start still works

Comment: Still works in 2021

Comment: This workaround does not work for Linux VMs (Xubuntu 20.04).

Comment: Yea, still works at Windows 10. What a horrible experience.